# “ITunesSoftwareService” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources."

Tags: xcode

I have seen others complain about this error. In my case I was able to trace it down to MacKeeper's Fast Cleanup feature.

I can reproduce the issue repeatedly with the following test:
1. With working version of Xcode 4.6, Clean, Build for OS Device & Archive: NO ERRORS
2. Kill Xcode
3. Start MacKeeper. Scan says there are several hundred "Junk" files. Press the "Fix this Problem" button. MacKeeper does its thing and reports all green.
4. Start up Xcode. Try to Clean, Build & Archive. Build fails with following error:

2013-02-06 16:45:17.568 Validation[39540:f07] Could not load framework at “file://localhost/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application%20Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/” (err = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "The bundle “ITunesSoftwareService” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources."

1. Here's the frustrating part. The only way to fix this is Re-install Xcode, Clean Build & Archive now works again. CLearly MacKeeper is removing something it should not!

I have reported this issue to MacKeeper but heard nothing back. Today I downloaded the latest update 2.4.1 and did my test with same results - Code broke again.

Can anyone else verify? I am ready to drop kick MacKeeper.

Comment: I have had the same problem twice now, and it seems to be related to MacKeeper as well. Don't remove MacKeeper, but don't use it to remove binaries clutter (or cache for that matter) from XCode

Comment: As a MacKeeper employee I would like to say thank you for your feedback.
For some reason this skipped our attention in the past, and we are sorry for this.
We are currently investigating the case, and most probably will add the mentioned application to the black list for binaries and cache cleaning tools. It might take a bit of time, in the meanwhile the previous answer is the best way to go around this.
The black list database is not connected to MacKeeper version and updates automatically when new items are added.